# Do you still pay internet egress fees if you use a load balancer?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

So I'm looking online at load balancers at Oracle Cloud etc. and their pricing is very confusing.

Oracle Cloud charges `$0.0113`/load balancer instance and `$0.0001`/1mbps traffic per hour.
They have a free tier, but for this example, let's pretend the free tier services and bandwidth (`$10TB` free/month) doesn't exist.

Does traffic that goes through the load balancer also add to the total bandwidth you use per month? Like cloud egress in general that costs `$0.0085`/GB? Or do you just pay the fee for the traffic that goes through the load balancer itself?

Microsoft Azure charges `$0.005`/GB of data "Data processed" with their load balancer.

If you used a compute server on their platform but put it behind a load balancer and disconnect it from the internet, are you still paying the `$0.0875`/GB of Internet Egress fees, or only the load balancer transfer fees of `$0.005`/GB?

What if you hosted something on another platform where egress didn't cost anything? Would you have to pay for internet egress, balancer egress, neither or both?

Same questions with Google Cloud. It costs about `$0.0074`/GB of data processed with the load balancer. Do you also have to pay egress fees (like `$0.085`/GB data transferred) or just `$0.0074`? Or both?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Okay, I apologize. I saw other similar questions so I thought it might be okay to ask, especially since it was apart of the Google Cloud Q&A section, with I think is an official Q&A section for Google Cloud?

Answer (score 2):

@nikolay pricing for LoadBalancer in GCP depend on the region where that LoadBalancer is located, i could not find the numbers you provided on our doc but generally speaking this is what you have to pay when you use LoadBalancers

- First 5 forwarding rules at a fixed price
- Each additional Forwarding rule at a fixed price per additional rule
- Ingress (Incoming data) processed by the LB per GB
- Egress (outgoing data from the LoadBalancer back to the caller) is charged at the normal rates

This docs explain it all

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#lb
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#all-networking-pricing

Answer (score 1):

In Google Cloud Platform, Internet Egress and Load Balancing costs are calculated separately.
Load Balancer is billed based on the amount of Ingress data processed (Ingress itself is free) and number of forwarding rules.
So in your example, if your load balancer is processing incoming data, you are paying $0.0074/GB;
If you are responding to those packets, then you are also being billed Egress fee for the appropriate tier.

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#all-networking-pricing) and estimate the cost yourself using the [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).